# Seleccionar filas por diferentes grupos en un Dataframe Python

Tags: python

Tengo un dataframe con mas de 30.000 filas y 4 columnas.
Las columnas están compuestas por *nombre*, *departamento*, *puesto de trabajo*, *salario*).
Tengo que incrementar en un 10% el salario de los 5 trabajadores con el salario más bajo de cada departamento.

```
df1=df.groupby(['Departamento','Nombre']).sum()

Nombre  Puesto de Trabajo   Departamento    Salario
AARON,  ELVIA J WATER RATE TAKER    WATER MGMNT 90744
AARON,  JEFFERY M   POLICE OFFICER  POLICE  84450
AARON,  KARINA  POLICE OFFICER  POLICE  84450
AARON,  KIMBERLEI R CHIEF CONTRACT EXPEDITER    GENERAL SERVICES    89880
ABAD JR,  VICENTE M CIVIL ENGINEER IV   WATER MGMNT 106836
ABARCA,  ANABEL ASST TO THE ALDERMAN    CITY COUNCIL    70764
ABARCA,  EMMANUEL   GENERAL LABORER - DSS   STREETS & SAN   41849
ABASCAL,  REECE E   TRAFFIC CONTROL AIDE-HOURLY OEMC    20051
ABBASI,  CHRISTOPHER    STAFF ASST TO THE ALDERMAN  CITY COUNCIL    49452
ABBATACOLA,  ROBERT J   ELECTRICAL MECHANIC AVIATION    93600
ABBATEMARCO,  JAMES J   FIRE ENGINEER-EMT   FIRE    100320
ABBATE,  TERRY M    POLICE OFFICER  POLICE  90618
ABBOTT,  BETTY L    FOSTER GRANDPARENT  FAMILY & SUPPORT    2756
ABBOTT,  LYNISE M   CLERK III   POLICE  46896
ABBRUZZESE,  WILLIAM J  INVESTIGATOR - IPRA II  IPRA    73920
ABDALLAH,  ZAID POLICE OFFICER  POLICE  74028
ABDELHADI,  ABDALMAHD   POLICE OFFICER  POLICE  81588
ABDELLATIF,  AREF R FIREFIGHTER (PER ARBITRATORS AWARD)-PARAMEDIC   FIRE    99228
ABDELMAJEID,  AZIZ  POLICE OFFICER  POLICE  81588
ABDOLLAHZADEH,  ALI FIREFIGHTER/PARAMEDIC   FIRE    88596
ABDUL-KARIM,  MUHAMMAD A    ENGINEERING TECHNICIAN VI   WATER MGMNT 108228
ABDULLAH,  DANIEL N FIREFIGHTER-EMT FIRE    92682
ABDULLAH,  KEVIN    LIEUTENANT  FIRE    111474
ABDULLAH,  LAKENYA N    CROSSING GUARD  OEMC    17846
ABDULLAH,  RASHAD J ELECTRICAL MECHANIC-AUTO-POLICE MTR MNT GENERAL SERVICES    93600
ABDULSATTAR,  MUDHAR    CIVIL ENGINEER II   WATER MGMNT 58536
ABDUL-SHAKUR,  TAHIR    GENERAL LABORER - DSS   STREETS & SAN   41849,6
ABDULWAHAB,  ABUUBAIDA  FOSTER GRANDPARENT  FAMILY & SUPPORT    2756
ABEJERO,  JASON V   POLICE OFFICER  POLICE  87384
ABERCROMBIE IV,  EARL S PARAMEDIC   FIRE    70380
ABERCROMBIE,  TIMOTHY   MOTOR TRUCK DRIVER  STREETS & SAN   72862,4
ABIOYE,  ADEWOLE A  LIBRARY ASSOCIATE - HOURLY  PUBLIC LIBRARY  25334,4
ABNEY,  PATRICK POLICE OFFICER  POLICE  46668
ABOUELKHEIR,  HASSAN A  SENIOR PROGRAMMER/ANALYST   FAMILY & SUPPORT    106836
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías agregar una muestra de tu dataframe? así podremos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Ya lo he agregado. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Por favor, pon la muestra _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden visualizar las imágenes, además así facilitarías los datos para poder manipularlos (copiar/pegar).

Comment: ok. lo he añadido como texto

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre la siguiente solución:

1. Escribir una función que reciba un sub-dataframe (se supone que será un grupo en el que todos los datos pertenecen a un mismo departamento), y que ordene ese sub-dataframe por el salario, tome los 5 primeros y les multiplique el salario por 1.1 (lo que equivale a subirlos un 10%)
2. Aplicar esa función al resultado de un `groupby()`
3. Re-asignar las filas que hayan sido modificadas al dataframe original.

Vamos por partes

### La función

La siguiente función haría lo descrito en el punto 1:

```py
def ajustar_salario(d):
  aux = d.sort_values(by="Salario").iloc[:5]
  aux.Salario *= 1.1
  return aux
```

Como ves recibimos un dataframe `d` al que aplicamos un `.sort_values()` para ordenar por el salario, y después aplicamos un `.iloc[:5]` para quedarnos con las cinco primeras filas. Serán los 5 salarios más bajos. Multiplicamos la columna `.Salario` por 1.1 y retornamos el resultado.

### Agrupar y aplicar

Esto es sencillo:

```
aux = df.groupby(["Departamento"]).apply(ajustar_salario)
aux = aux.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

La función `.groupby()` agrupa todas las filas por departamentos. Cada grupo resultante se pasará como parámetro a `ajustar_salario` que es la función antes mostrada. Con los resultados que ésta vaya devolviendo, se construye un nuevo dataframe `aux`. Este tendrá sólo los casos en los que hemos incrementado el salario. El índice de `aux` será un multi-índice de dos niveles, siendo el primero el departamento y el segundo la columna índice original de `df`. Gracias a `reset_index()` eliminamos el primer nivel (departamento).

El resultado (tomando como entrada los datos que suministras en la pregunta) sería este:

```html
                     Nombre         Puesto de Trabajo          Departamento    Salario
9      ABBATACOLA, ROBERT J       ELECTRICAL MECHANIC              AVIATION  102960.00
8       ABBASI, CHRISTOPHER  STAFF ASST TO THE ALD...          CITY COUNCIL   54397.20
5            ABARCA, ANABEL      ASST TO THE ALDERMAN          CITY COUNCIL   77840.40
12          ABBOTT, BETTY L        FOSTER GRANDPARENT      FAMILY & SUPPORT    3031.60
27    ABDULWAHAB, ABUUBAIDA        FOSTER GRANDPARENT      FAMILY & SUPPORT    3031.60
33    ABOUELKHEIR, HASSAN A  SENIOR PROGRAMMER/ANA...      FAMILY & SUPPORT  117519.60
29   ABERCROMBIE IV, EARL S                 PARAMEDIC                  FIRE   77418.00
19       ABDOLLAHZADEH, ALI     FIREFIGHTER/PARAMEDIC                  FIRE   97455.60
21       ABDULLAH, DANIEL N           FIREFIGHTER-EMT                  FIRE  101950.20
17       ABDELLATIF, AREF R  FIREFIGHTER (PER ARBI...                  FIRE  109150.80
10     ABBATEMARCO, JAMES J         FIRE ENGINEER-EMT                  FIRE  110352.00
3        AARON, KIMBERLEI R  CHIEF CONTRACT EXPEDITER      GENERAL SERVICES   98868.00
14    ABBRUZZESE, WILLIAM J    INVESTIGATOR - IPRA II                  IPRA   81312.00
24       ABDULLAH, RASHAD J  ELECTRICAL MECHANIC-A...  MNT GENERAL SERVICES  102960.00
23      ABDULLAH, LAKENYA N            CROSSING GUARD                  OEMC   19630.60
7          ABASCAL, REECE E  TRAFFIC CONTROL AIDE-...                  OEMC   22056.10
32           ABNEY, PATRICK            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   51334.80
13         ABBOTT, LYNISE M                 CLERK III                POLICE   51585.60
15           ABDALLAH, ZAID            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   81430.80
16     ABDELHADI, ABDALMAHD            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   89746.80
18        ABDELMAJEID, AZIZ            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   89746.80
31        ABIOYE, ADEWOLE A  LIBRARY ASSOCIATE - H...        PUBLIC LIBRARY   27867.84
6          ABARCA, EMMANUEL     GENERAL LABORER - DSS         STREETS & SAN   46033.90
26      ABDUL-SHAKUR, TAHIR     GENERAL LABORER - DSS         STREETS & SAN   46034.56
30     ABERCROMBIE, TIMOTHY        MOTOR TRUCK DRIVER         STREETS & SAN   80148.64
25      ABDULSATTAR, MUDHAR         CIVIL ENGINEER II           WATER MGMNT   64389.60
0            AARON, ELVIA J          WATER RATE TAKER           WATER MGMNT   99818.40
4        ABAD JR, VICENTE M         CIVIL ENGINEER IV           WATER MGMNT  117519.60
20  ABDUL-KARIM, MUHAMMAD A  ENGINEERING TECHNICIA...           WATER MGMNT  119050.80
```

### Reasignar al dataframe original

Como ves en el resultado anterior, el dataframe `aux` no contiene todos los datos del original, sino solo aquellos cuyo salario hemos incrementado (los cinco de salarios más bajo dentro de cada departamento).

Solo queda volver a asignar estos datos modificados al dataframe original. Por suerte en `aux` tenemos como índice los mismos números del dataframe `df` inicial. Si te fijas, por ejemplo, la primera fila de `aux` tiene índice 9, y ese es el índice que correspondía al trabajador "ABBATACOLA, ROBERT J" en la tabla inicial.

Así que podemos usar `aux.index` como selector de qué filas queremos modificar en `df`, para que las no seleccionadas queden como estaban:

```py
df.loc[aux.index, "Salario"] = aux["Salario"]
```

El `df` final:

```html
                     Nombre         Puesto de Trabajo          Departamento    Salario
0            AARON, ELVIA J          WATER RATE TAKER           WATER MGMNT   99818.40
1          AARON, JEFFERY M            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   84450.00
2             AARON, KARINA            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   84450.00
3        AARON, KIMBERLEI R  CHIEF CONTRACT EXPEDITER      GENERAL SERVICES   98868.00
4        ABAD JR, VICENTE M         CIVIL ENGINEER IV           WATER MGMNT  117519.60
5            ABARCA, ANABEL      ASST TO THE ALDERMAN          CITY COUNCIL   77840.40
6          ABARCA, EMMANUEL     GENERAL LABORER - DSS         STREETS & SAN   46033.90
7          ABASCAL, REECE E  TRAFFIC CONTROL AIDE-...                  OEMC   22056.10
8       ABBASI, CHRISTOPHER  STAFF ASST TO THE ALD...          CITY COUNCIL   54397.20
9      ABBATACOLA, ROBERT J       ELECTRICAL MECHANIC              AVIATION  102960.00
10     ABBATEMARCO, JAMES J         FIRE ENGINEER-EMT                  FIRE  110352.00
11          ABBATE, TERRY M            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   90618.00
12          ABBOTT, BETTY L        FOSTER GRANDPARENT      FAMILY & SUPPORT    3031.60
13         ABBOTT, LYNISE M                 CLERK III                POLICE   51585.60
14    ABBRUZZESE, WILLIAM J    INVESTIGATOR - IPRA II                  IPRA   81312.00
15           ABDALLAH, ZAID            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   81430.80
16     ABDELHADI, ABDALMAHD            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   89746.80
17       ABDELLATIF, AREF R  FIREFIGHTER (PER ARBI...                  FIRE  109150.80
18        ABDELMAJEID, AZIZ            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   89746.80
19       ABDOLLAHZADEH, ALI     FIREFIGHTER/PARAMEDIC                  FIRE   97455.60
20  ABDUL-KARIM, MUHAMMAD A  ENGINEERING TECHNICIA...           WATER MGMNT  119050.80
21       ABDULLAH, DANIEL N           FIREFIGHTER-EMT                  FIRE  101950.20
22          ABDULLAH, KEVIN                LIEUTENANT                  FIRE  111474.00
23      ABDULLAH, LAKENYA N            CROSSING GUARD                  OEMC   19630.60
24       ABDULLAH, RASHAD J  ELECTRICAL MECHANIC-A...  MNT GENERAL SERVICES  102960.00
25      ABDULSATTAR, MUDHAR         CIVIL ENGINEER II           WATER MGMNT   64389.60
26      ABDUL-SHAKUR, TAHIR     GENERAL LABORER - DSS         STREETS & SAN   46034.56
27    ABDULWAHAB, ABUUBAIDA        FOSTER GRANDPARENT      FAMILY & SUPPORT    3031.60
28         ABEJERO, JASON V            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   87384.00
29   ABERCROMBIE IV, EARL S                 PARAMEDIC                  FIRE   77418.00
30     ABERCROMBIE, TIMOTHY        MOTOR TRUCK DRIVER         STREETS & SAN   80148.64
31        ABIOYE, ADEWOLE A  LIBRARY ASSOCIATE - H...        PUBLIC LIBRARY   27867.84
32           ABNEY, PATRICK            POLICE OFFICER                POLICE   51334.80
33    ABOUELKHEIR, HASSAN A  SENIOR PROGRAMMER/ANA...      FAMILY & SUPPORT  117519.60
```